# Magento2.4: Minicart has no content

Tags: magento2.4, mini-cart

I'm working on a custom theme and having issues updating the minicart content. The minicart loads, but always says there are no items in the cart. If I continue towards the checkout page, there are items in my cart. Adding items to my cart on the product page works, but again the addition to the cart is not reflected in the minicart as it remains empty.

I've tried:

- rewriting theme templates with the base files from module_checkout
- loading the minicart directly in a phtml instead of using the xml configuration.
- switching towards default theme does show the minicart content
- I'm not including any custom JS yet in my theme at this point
- Parent theme is Luma
- On the frontend there is only 1 external extension active, namely the Magezon Page Builder which is only used for the actual page content, the header is fully built using the default.xml

[image: Minicart remains empty]

My default.xml config related to the minicart:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
                </block>
```

The templates in `theme/Magento_Checkout/templates` are identical towards the default Magento Checkout module.

Template Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml:

```
<div>
    <div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper absolute top-0 right-0 md:relative">
        <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
           data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
            <span class="counter qty empty"
                  data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
                <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="counter-label">
                <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                    <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
            <div class="block block-minicart empty"
                 data-role="dropdownDialog"
                 data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
                <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "[data-block='minicart']": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
                },
                "*": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.minicart-wrapper').hover(function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').addClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').show();

            }, function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').removeClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It feels like the minicart is working, but the JS isn't triggering to get cart data.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but have a similar problem and wondering if you figured it out.